# Tcl zipfile and openssl symmetric enc strange behavior

Tags: openssl, tcl

I have a script that gathers some information on a chosen file, then encrypts the file using OpenSSL. zipfile zips up the encrypted file and two other files that contain the file information and salting information, much abridged:

```
exec openssl enc -seed-cfb -iter $iter -md $digest -in $intail -out $intail.data -nosalt -pbkdf2 -pass pass:$key
if {[file isfile $intail.rd] > 0} {
    file delete $intail.rd
}
zipfile::mkzip::mkzip $intail.rd footer.bin header.bin $intail.data
exec openssl enc -camellia-256-ofb -md sm3 -in $intail.rd -out $intail.red -nosalt -pbkdf2 -pass pass:$final_key
```

and do decipher the file it just goes in reverse:

```
if {[catch {exec openssl enc -camellia-256-ofb -d -md sm3 -in $intail -out $final_in.rd -nosalt -pbkdf2 -pass pass:$final_key} msg]} {
    file delete $final_in.rd
    tk_messageBox -message "Bad password, offset, or other problem, returning"
    return
}
if {[zipfile::decode::iszip $final_in.rd] < 1} {
    set chna [chan names]
    foreach ch $chna {
        chan close $ch
    }
    file delete $final_in.rd
    tk_messageBox -message "bad input file, wrong password or cipher mode"
    return
}
zipfile::decode::unzipfile $final_in.rd ./
```

This is where the problem lies. The script works fine, and will go on to decipher the original file after this unzipping. However, if I encrypt a file running the script under Windows, and then try to decipher the file running the same exact script under Linux, the zip file produced by the first OpenSSL "camellia" deciphering run will be corrupt garbage, and vice versa. (the script cd's to the working directory, so there's no path info to be accounted for)

If I replace the final "camellia" encryption run with a self contained pass of rc4, using the same exact variables, it works fine between both OS's:

```
exec openssl enc -seed-cfb -iter $iter -md $digest -in $intail -out $intail.data -nosalt -pbkdf2 -pass pass:$key

if {[file isfile $intail.rd] > 0} {
    file delete $intail.rd
}
zipfile::mkzip::mkzip $intail.rd footer.bin header.bin $intail.data -directory ./

set outfile [open $intail.red wb]
rc4::rc4 -infile $intail.rd -out $outfile -key $final_key
close $outfile
```

deciphering:

```
set outfile [open $final_in.rd wb]
rc4::rc4 -infile $intail -out $outfile -key $final_key
close $outfile

if {[zipfile::decode::iszip $final_in.rd] < 1} {
    set chna [chan names]
    foreach ch $chna {
        chan close $ch
    }
    file delete $final_in.rd
    tk_messageBox -message "bad input file file, wrong password or cipher mode"
    return
}
zipfile::decode::unzipfile $final_in.rd ./
```

Additionally, if I cut out the final "camellia" encryption and leave the final result as the zip file, I can work the script between OS's just fine. So it seems that the first "seed" encryption of the file works fine, zipping up the encrypted file with the two tagalong files works fine, it's just the final encryption of the zip file that won't work correctly between OS's using OpenSSL's symmetric enc command.

In short, the script works fine using Windows, and it works fine using Linux. Only when I encrypting with one and decrypting with the other is there a problem. I'm really at a loss.

Comment: What are the checksums of the *.rd on either system (Linux, Windows)? How did you transfer the files between the systems (i.e. could some unwanted character enc/ dec interfere?)

Comment: Also, what are the checksums of your key files on either system? How were they transferred?

Comment: Closing all channels, while not your problem, is likely to lead to other problems; it may include entirely uninvolved things. (However, the connection to the Xserver isn't typically exposed as a channel so the GUI will keep working.)

Comment: If you'd been using `exec` with input redirection to deliver binary data, that would have been an obvious thing to look at (as that will vary between platforms due to varying defaults) but that doesn't appear to be the problem here.

Comment: The hash of the zip file is the same between systems if I substitute the RC4 package to do the final encryption run where it correctly works between systems. The key is a non-issue, as it's manually entered before being hashed up and salted. As the script works fine between systems if I substitute TCL's RC4 package to do the final encryption in lieu of OpenSSL's camellia (or any other OpenSSL cipher, I've tested) tells me that neither the zip file nor the password hashing is the issue. The files are not transferred between systems, they're kept on a file server accessible by both systems.

Comment: Closing all of the channels became a habit with ```zipfile``` as it wasn't closing properly otherwise on error, In fact, you're the one that reported this issue several months ago, I think it may be fixed now in tcllib 1.2, I haven't looked.